# Remove unnecessary pairs from reflexive asymetric transitive relation

Tags: numpy, graph, scipy, relation, minimum-spanning-tree

I have a reflexive asymetric transitive relation represented as an `n`x`n` sparse `scipy` `csr` matrix.

Now as a result of some transformations I am left with many 'unnecessary' pairs:

```
set([('a','b'),('b','c'),('a','c')])
```

I need to remove pairs `('a','c')` that can be seen as 'direct' edges when there are 'indirect' ones.

First I was thinking this is a special [spanning arborescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27_algorithm), but actually in the following case:

```
set([('a','b'),('b','d'),('a','c'),('c','d')])
```

... no pair should be removed. The result is not necessarily a tree.

- Is there a name for this kind of problem?
- Is there an implementation in `scipy`?
- If not, can you suggest an efficient algorithm in `python`/`numpy`/`scipy`?

**EDIT: Seems like this is called a *transitive reduction*?
 But there is no `scipy.sparse.csgraph` implementation?**

**EDIT:** I guess to get an acyclic directed graph I would have to (temporarily) remove the 'reflexiveness', but this is not a problem.

Comment: Can't you just check for overlap between the matrix and its square/powers?

Comment: But the square/powers still has the 'indirect' edges - or not? So everything is overlapping.

Comment: I assumed from your samples that the "reflexive" (that means "self", right?) edges are not explicitly modeled. If they are, you'd have to remove the diagonal before multiplying. Then the square should only contain the endpoints of paths of length two, so these should be removed if they occur in the original adjacency. No clue whether this is efficient, though.

Comment: Oh ok, I was not aware of that. It is probably not particularly efficient but certainly an option.

Comment: I am a bit disappointed that there is no `scipy` implementation but I guess alternatively, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078696/im-trying-to-perform-the-transitive-reduction-of-directed-graph-in-python

Comment: Or go with `networkx`: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.dag.transitive_reduction.html

Comment: @PaulPanzer, I think your approach is actually referred to in Wikipedia: "They let A be the adjacency matrix of the given directed acyclic graph, and B be the adjacency matrix of its transitive closure [...]. Then an edge uv belongs to the transitive reduction if and only if there is a nonzero entry in row u and column v of matrix A, and there is a zero entry in the same position of the matrix product AB. In this construction, the nonzero elements of the matrix AB represent pairs of vertices connected by paths of length two or more."

Comment: So `A - A.dot(tran_clos(A))`. I will check this now.

Comment: How do you get tran_clos? That would be the adjacency of A + A^2 + A^3 + ... right?

Comment: @PaulPanzer, currently trying to figure this out. `scipy.connected_components` does not work. Could it be that only A^2 + ...

Comment: @PaulPanzer I am starting to think that I misunderstood the Wikipedia entry. I think there, the transitive closure actually refers to the matrix that we have at hand and that we want to get the reduction of. This recipe is only used to argue the complexity.

Comment: If I were you I'd start checking out `networkx`. My (limited) experience with it is not too bad. Why reinvent the wheel, unless you want to educate yourself?

Comment: Yeah currently getting anoyed with the lacking implementations in `scipy`. But I am implementing your solution now. Maybe later switch to `networkx`

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is called **Transitive Reduction** of a directed acyclic graph.

The following code should solve the problem, although it might be far from optimal:

```
def transitive_reduction(edges): # edges is irreflexive and scipy sparse bool
    reduction = edges.copy()
    num, i    = 99,2
    while num > 0:
        new        = edges**i
        num        = len(new.nonzero()[0])
        reduction  = reduction > new
        i         += 1
        reduction.eliminate_zeros() # might or might not be required
    return reduction
```

Explanation: As long as paths of this length exists, we remove from `reduction` all direct paths for which there are indirect paths of length `i`.

Credits to @PaulPanzer.